# how to do search functionality using rest api flutter

Tags: search, flutter

I want to search the products data and show the searched data in the below as list up to 15 items if 16 item is entered than automatically the first item will be deleted.can any one help me how to do this in flutter

Comment: How are you entering those 15 items?? Via the search service response or on any button click & filtering local data?

Comment: when we search the item in the search box it will store in the local db

Answer (score 0):

As you written

> when we search the item in the search box it will store in the local db

So you can get only first  15 items using the same query. By that using pagination you can show remaining items. I can't get the use case of removing the top item if there are more than `n` items in list.

But if you want, you can do this by two ways.

**First**, putting items one by one in the list. Inside this loop if item count is more than 15 after inserting a new item, just remove the first item

> list.removeAt(0);

**Second**, add the items in array, check for length. If length is greater than 15 get the remaining number & run

> list.removeRange(0, );

This will remove the items from top

Comment: Give me any example for search functionality @Aakash Kumar

Comment: Please share the code you have as what you have tried so we can understand the issue.